# eval and binding: what are they useful for?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

According to [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html), `kernel#eval` takes a binding object as the second argument as follows:

```
Const = 7
p eval("Const", binding)  # => 7
```

The method `eval` can be used with an object returned by a method `get_binding` that accepts one parameter:

```
def get_binding(param)
  return binding
end
n = get_binding(7)
p eval("param", n)  # => 7
```

In the first piece of code, we get the value of `Const`, and in the second piece of code, we get the value of `param`. If we use `eval` and `binding` to retrieve values that we already know, what are these methods useful for?

Comment: These are simplistic examples of how `Binding` and `eval` *work*, *not* realistic real-world applications of how they are *used*. In particular, using `eval` with a constant string doesn't make sense, you'd typically use it with a string that includes some unknown or dynamically built parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sake of discussion, lets say you are working on a template engine - which will process a given text and replace the Ruby code in it with the its value.  We can use `eval` for that.

Being a general purpose engine, the template text should allow usage of Ruby variables, whose value will be defined in the caller's binding.  In such cases, by passing binding to the `eval`, we can allow user's binding to be used for variable evaluation.

A rudimentary, not elegant, approach is demonstrated below:

```
template = "Hello @first_name@ @last_name@"

def process(template, b)
    vars = template.scan(/@(\w+)@/).flatten
    vars.each {|v| template = template.gsub("@#{v}@", eval("#{v}", b)) }
    return template
end

first_name = "Wand"
last_name = "Maker"

str = process(template, binding)
p str
#=> "Hello Wand Maker"

first_name = "Rubeus"
last_name = "Hagrid"
p process(template, binding)
#=> "Hello Rubeus Hagrid"
```

A somewhat similar approach has been used in ERB, Ruby's in-built template engine.  You can take a look at [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb#L860)